# Conflict prototype.js and another library

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do I solve the problem of conflict between two libraries (including prototype.js once put into a tailspin all other libraries) that make me useless the whole script? How can I include prototype.js without causing problems? I know jquery.noconflict () but I do not know where to include it in prototype.js (since it is the last file that is causing the conflict).
Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a version of prototype called [ProtoSafe](http://ajaxian.com/archives/protosafe-eases-compatibility-for-prototype).

Since,

> ..The issue is that Prototype extends the    (small p) prototype of
>   various elements to do its magic, and you can't    un-do that (which
>   is what would be required in this case).

From the Protosafe description

> Prototype extends native data type prototypes which makes it very
>   convenient for the developer but when interacting with 3rd party code
>   not written for Prototype, these prototype extensions can cause
>   compatibility issues. The most common is the Array for-in loop issue
>   where by doing a for in loop over an array you get its indexed values
>   plus the method names of all the added helper methods.
>
> **> The benefit that ProtoSafe provides is that it allows Prototype to be
>   used alongside 3rd party code without causing these compatibility
>   issues. Also it can be run against multiple frameworks which is good
>   in the widget environment.**

Comment: @FilippoAlessi: They seem to work for me. The links are valid. You must be behind a firewall or something.